# connectionString outside SQL server with App.config file

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection, connection-string, app-config

I have a console application and in the App.config I need to add a connectionString to another SQL server that is in the same network.

If I try the connectionString to a local server by only passing the Server='localhost' its worked but I cannot make it work for an outside server.

Thanks

Here is the connection file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Server=LocalServer;database=DAtaBase;user=UserName;pwd=Password" name="Connection"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is the location of the outside server? Give us little more details.

Comment: Please paste your connection string and the error you get.

Comment: I have modified the question and I have included the connection config file

Comment: here is a link to [C# connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com) that will show you how to configure your connection strings to many different databases.. also `Google could have saved you a lot of time and trouble` when asking a question please read the `faq` on how to ask a question on this site as well

Comment: You are using the same DNS *and* instance name of the server right? I.e. `SERVER=MySqlNode\WebSql` or `SERVER=10.0.0.4\SQLEXPRESS` et al. Also, as @MethodMan said, read up on the connection strings.

Comment: Ok and to what LocalServer resolves to? I suppose to nothing...
You need an actual address of remote server with database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example connection to outer server:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Namespace.Settings.outerSQL" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.100\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=database_name;User ID=user;Password=password"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

You need address to remote server and credentials provided (if it's not Windows auth, for which you use "Integrated Security").

Answer (score 0):

inside of a app.config / web.Config file you would have the following and this is a simple and easy way to connect to a sql server database.. also confirm what database you are using because the connection string can be different depending on the DBMS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConn" connectionString="Data Source=the name of your database;User Id=UserName;Password=Password;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>  
</configuration>
```